# How to display using PHP language, highest values from column inside HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, list

```
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="panel panel-inverse">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">TOP 5 BUNNY KILLERS</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul class="media-list user-list">
           <?php echo $output ?>
            <?php echo $output ?>
             <?php echo $output ?>
              <?php echo $output ?>
               <?php echo $output ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

$sql = "SELECT Username, BunnyKilled FROM users order by BunnyKilled DESC LIMIT 5;";
$con=mysqli_connect("yes","yes","yes","yes");
$results =  array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$results = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$output = '';

foreach ($results as $result) {
$output = '  <li class="media"> <div class="media-left"> <a href="#">  <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user9.png" alt=""> </a> </div> <div class="media-body"> <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="">'. $result['Username'] . '</a></h4> <span>' . $result['BunnyKilled'] . '</span> bunny killed</div> </li>' ;
    }
```

I'm also using

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

for showing personal information of the bunny killer, but the top 5 bunny killers I want to show every killer ordered by their number of bunny killed. after what it didn't work, I put var dump and this is what I got

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Username"]=>
    string(19) "Abdulhamit_Yildirim"
    ["BunnyKilled"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Username"]=>
    string(4) "Ampo"
    ["BunnyKilled"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Username"]=>
    string(15) "Timothy_Bronson"
    ["BunnyKilled"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Username"]=>
    string(6) "Rvmses"
    ["BunnyKilled"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Username"]=>
    string(3) "Esy"
    ["BunnyKilled"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

just updated var_dump results which i've put it after fetch

Comment: My question is how to fetch (find) those highest values from column and to echo them inside HTML code.

Comment: For one thing, there shouldn't be brackets around this `SELECT (Username, BunnyKilled)`.

Comment: You also can't just select and echo, you need to execute the query.

Comment: I have to ask again, what happens when you run your query? Wrong result? Error messages? Computer bursts into flames? I would recommend that you go through some PHP + MySQL tutorials... this is pretty PHP + MySQL 101 and there are _many_ tutorials if you do a quick google search.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It gives me the that error with mysql_Fetch_assoc.  What I want to do is, to fetch from column named "BunnyKilled" the top five desc numbers and foreach them inside my html, using the first code i've typed. If you can give me the correct tutorials I will read, thanks.

Comment: You never execute your query. Regarding _"If you can give me the correct tutorials"_ you will need to do the research yourself. It's off-topic to ask for off-site resources. But like I said, there are plenty of tutorials if you just do a google search.

Comment: It appears that you have corrected/vandalized your own question with several edits.  Now your question makes no sense and the previous good advice in comments is now meaningless as well.  I don't even know how how far to rollback this question.  I'm voting to close as Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL query should look something like:

SELECT * FROM looneytunes order by BunnyKilled DESC LIMIT 5;

The top 5 are by the order by, limit 5.

Your php should look something like:

```
   <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT Username, BunnyKilled FROM users order by BunnyKilled DESC LIMIT 5;";

            $results =  array();
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $results = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $output = '';

            foreach ($results as $row) {

        $output .= '  <li class="media"> <div class="media-left"> <a href="#">  <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user9.png" alt=""> </a> </div> <div class="media-body"> <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="">'. $row['Username'] . '</a></h4> <span>' . $row['BunnyKilled'] . '</span> bunnies killed</div> </li>' ;
            }

        echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: That will definitely throw syntax errors all over the place. You can't just write HTML inside a PHP-block.

Comment: absolutely right.. I just ran with an answer. fixing it

Comment: just for the record, fixed it...

Comment: I'm getting yntax error, unexpected '=' and the $oputput. = ' <li>   I will try to fix it, thanks for trying to help me @GuyL

Comment: Im writing the code a bit on the fly. I'll update it

Comment: Yes, I fixed it, but it shows only one looneytuney character instead of showing five, and it shows randomly (highest value is 15, lowest is 0, but it shows a character with 2 bunny killed)

Comment: can you add the raw query results to your question?

Comment: done @GuyL. I'm still trying to fix it

Comment: I don't see the raw results from the query... also, why did you seperate the echo $output from the rest of the code

Comment: because If I didn't separate it, it would show at the top of the page. I put the <?php echo $output ?> inside the <ul> and it's okay, the single problem is that it won't show the highest values

Comment: then its best if you display all of the code... I can't be of more help without it

Comment: Done @GuyL. Anything which you want me to add up?

Comment: try running the mysql query you added and showing the raw data, let's see if its the sql part or a piece of the code... if the raw results are as you want, ten next try to run the code with var_dump right afer the results = fetch_all

Comment: I edited the main post with var_dump. I don't really know how to run mysql query / raw data. Here's a screenshot how it looks right now.  (Instead of bunny i put bandits) https://i.imgur.com/USDlbec.png

Comment: So 5 lines are displayed... I'll try changing the variable namea

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: '. $row['Username'] . ' ' . $row['BunnyKilled'] . ' bunnies killed ' ;  where should I put ? and the old code should I remove something from it?

Comment: I replaced the variable $result inside the foreach loop with $row, because it might have called the query variable...

Comment: If I replace $result with $row, it gives me error Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array .  Beside that, where should I replace / add the '. $row['Username'] . ' ' . $row['BunnyKilled'] . ' bunnies killed ' ; } ?  Because whereever i add it, it gives me the same error (object of type)

Comment: replcae result with row, only inside the foreach loop, as I fixex in my query

Comment: It works perfectly now, but it modifies my rest of php Notice: Undefined index: BackpackSlots in ... on line 48  I will try to modify it, thanks! +1 rep.

Comment: happy to help  :)